# Vscode is ignoring the "terminal.integrated.shell.osx" setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

`VsCode Version: 1.82.3 (Universal)`

I have this in my global settings.json

`"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh",`

But when I try to open a local shell:

[image]

I see this error:

[image]

Also, I'm suppose to have this option, but it does not exist:

[image]

Setting "terminal.integrated.cwd" also does nothing- it still looks for it in `/usr/bin/zsh`

This also does nothing:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh",
    }
},
```

I tried setting this with all profiles as well:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh", // also I see this isn't a valid option but for some reason "zsh (2)" is!
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "zsh",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh",
    },
},
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh",
    },
},
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/zsh",
    },
},
```

## Update

Looks like this is a really gross bug, and no workarounds I have found work for me:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148572
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148572#issuecomment-1405526996

This is a problem when trying to open a local terminal when in a dev container, but outside of a dev container it opens it at path `/bin/zsh` which "works" cause that exists, but it's still broken and not using any path configurations.